# tagging a list of gerrits as a label

Tags: android, git, gerrit, repository

Is there a way to tag a list of gerrits to a label...after tagging,if I do a repo sync of this label,these gerrits should get synced to workspace..is there an option like dat?has anyone done this before?Any advice on this is much appreciated.

```
Commands used to do repo sync

    $repo init -u git://git.SERVER.com/platform/manifest.git -b refs/tags/label -m versioned.xml #Eg to sync to a label
     <code snippet>

    $ repo sync # syncing the code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create tag:

repo forall -c "git tag -a -m \"  [ tag description ] \"  [ tag-name ] "

Push tags to remote repository:

repo forall -c "git push origin [tag-name]"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit your .repo/manifest.xml revision to point to perticular tag... Add default revision as tag name. it will sync to provided tag only..

Comment: how to create a tag in the first place with a list of gerrits..lets say 12345, 23456,34567...